# Unable to connect to MongoDB from Nest using Mongoose (locally)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

i have a weird fail from my nestjs application while connecting to mongodb using mongoose:

```
[08:08:26] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[08:08:31] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +61ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] CacheModule dependencies initialized +27ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] GraphQLSchemaBuilderModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] RedisCacheModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:08:35     LOG [InstanceLoader] GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:09:05   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:09:38   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
[Nest] 21652  - 16.11.2021, 08:10:11   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...
```

Mongo runs in docker with: `docker run --name my-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:latest`. I can perfectly reach it with Robo 3T and with mongosh shell and with Intellij DB tab via 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017' or 'mongodb://localhost', but not through the nest app.

Here is my app.module.ts, the connection string is hardcoded for clarity sake:

```
/** @format */

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CompanyModule } from './company/company.module';
import { PersonModule } from './person/person.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { CallerModule } from './caller/caller.module';
import { RedisCacheModule } from './caching/redisCache.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    RedisCacheModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      playground: true,
      sortSchema: true,
    }),
    // MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_HOST),
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'),
    CompanyModule,
    PersonModule,
    CallerModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And environment:

```
[System Information]
OS Version     : Windows 10
NodeJS Version : v14.17.2
NPM Version    : 7.24.2

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 8.1.4

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 8.1.2
schematics version       : 8.0.4
mongoose version         : 9.0.1
graphql version          : 9.1.1
swagger version          : 5.1.4
testing version          : 8.1.2
common version           : 8.1.2
config version           : 1.0.3
axios version            : 0.0.3
core version             : 8.1.2
cli version              : 8.1.4
```

This set up was already used in my last project where it worked fine. Also, exactly this code works on my colleagues machines, they even have same node and npm versions (project reqs). So it seems like an issue on my side, but then again, i did not change anything since last nest project.

1. What is the reason of failing to connect to mongo?
2. How to debug/trace this error?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps a firewall doesn't think Nest should connect to localhost?

Comment: Don't think so, since connecting in my old project works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps fixed the problem:

1. File - Invalidate Chaches in IntelliJ, clear file system and local history, clear log caches and indexes, clear shared indexes. *After that I got warning about my Node v16.*
2. Switch to Node v14, `rm node_modules` from project root and then run `npm i`.